# Upload file in chunks with unknown length

Tags: google-drive-api

Can you give me an example (html or java) to implement the upload file in chunks. How can I upload a file If the length is unknown at the time of the request? I found this way https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable but I can't understand how can I say to the server the stream is terminated.

Thank you in advance.
aGO!

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you an example with the google drive sdk, but I can tell you how it's done with the raw HTTP requests.

First you have to [initiate a resumable upload session](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable), after which you can make partial uploads with unknown size by setting the `Content-Range` header to something like this `0-262144/*` for the first 256 KB, or whatever the size of your chunks are (they have to be multiples of 256KB as per the documentation).

You make requests like this to upload intermediate chunks until you get to the final chunk, which should be smaller than those fixed intermediate chunks. This last chunk will complete the file upload by setting the `Content-Range` field to `<byte interval of the chunk>/<final size of file>`.

The final size of the file can be calculated before the last request: number of requests * 256 KB + size of last chunk.

The algorithm is exemplified better here: http://pragmaticjoe.blogspot.ro/2015/10/uploading-files-with-unknown-size-using.html